# Using a custom TrueType font in spans of text

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am putting together a book using pdfTeX (from the TeX Live distribution on OSX), and part of the book involves a fictional dictionary for a constructed language. What I would like to do is define a command called, say, `\conlang` which switches to what is essentially a symbol font for the duration of that command. The .ttf also needs to be embedded in the .pdf.

I have found a number of tutorials on how to change the font family for the entire book, and I have found tutorials on how to change the font when using a package-specified font, but nothing for how to build the commands that actually load the fontfamily and make it available without building an entire package.

Comment: Does this link help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/27635

Comment: @karlhoeller That looks like it might be helpful, thanks. Why didn't that come up in my extensive searching?

Comment: @karlhoeller Unfortunately, no, the stuff there didn't help. It's not actually selecting the font I provided - it's just complaining about a missing T5xxx.fd file, and that t.se page doesn't explain anything about generating them.

Comment: Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with `fontspec` package, it's quite easy to use, say, `\fontspec{Font Name}`. However, it is rather complicated to use a new TrueType font in pdfTeX for a TeX beginner.

Comment: @LeoLiu I'm not a TeX beginner - this just isn't something I've had to do before (and it seems like nobody ever does this). Does that linked-to article also apply to TeXLive on OSX? I'm not a fan of mucking about with packaged installation files. There's a reason I don't run Slackware anymore. :)

Comment: @fluffy: `ttf2tfm` and other tools work same on TeX Live and MiKTeX, no matter you use OSX or Windows or Linux. BTW, why not use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @LeoLiu I'm just using pdfTeX because of familiarity and not bothering to learn about the newer things. :) I'll look into them now, thanks.